# Google Maps crashes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

For some reason I can't get MapView working. 
I've spend a couple of days doining research to it, and my code looking good (which means it's looks exactly like different tutorials), but everytime I launch it, it crashes. Eclipse nor the console info won't display an error.

Does anyone has a solution?

The HelloMapActivity.java file:

```
package com.com.google.maps;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

The main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mapview"
  android:clickable="true" 
  android:enabled="true" 
  android:apiKey="<Api-key>" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And at last, the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.com.google.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".HelloMapActivity"   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

This said LogCat:

```
11-01 22:22:56.376: D/ddm-heap(193): Got feature list request
11-01 22:22:56.826: W/dalvikvm(193): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Lcom/com/google/maps/HelloMapActivity;(0x6285ff78):0x11f940 ref [Lcom/google/android/maps/MapActivity;] Lcom/google/android/maps/MapActivity;(0x6285ff78):0x11ee40
11-01 22:22:56.826: W/dalvikvm(193): (Lcom/com/google/maps/HelloMapActivity; had used a different Lcom/google/android/maps/MapActivity; during pre-verification)
11-01 22:22:56.826: W/dalvikvm(193): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/com/google/maps/HelloMapActivity; (41)
11-01 22:22:56.826: W/dalvikvm(193): Link of class 'Lcom/com/google/maps/HelloMapActivity;' failed
11-01 22:22:56.826: D/AndroidRuntime(193): Shutting down VM
11-01 22:22:56.826: W/dalvikvm(193): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
11-01 22:22:56.826: E/AndroidRuntime(193): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:209)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:203)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-01 22:22:56.877: E/AndroidRuntime(193):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 22:22:56.916: I/dalvikvm(193): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
11-01 22:22:56.916: E/dalvikvm(193): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: why are you using the fully qualified object name for MapView?

Comment: Because for now I only try to reproduce the example-script before I implement it in my own project.
But what are your suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and figured out it came from the internet connection (also can not access the Internet through browser). I tried launch the AVD from the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" and it was working. Hope that will help some body.

Answer (score 0):

Can u put some logs for the crash , also try adding below permission to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"> </uses-permission>
```

Comment: No Solution, it still crashes at launch. 
I've added the logs in the original post. 
What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I think ou need to try and add

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> ```

to your manifest.

Comment: No solution :( its still crashing

Answer (score 0):

You need `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

As a child of the  tag in the manifest. ala

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".HelloMapActivity"   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *11-01 22:22:56.826: W/dalvikvm(193): (Lcom/com/google/maps/HelloMapActivity; had used a different Lcom/google/android/maps/MapActivity; during pre-verification)*

I am wondering if your installation and setup was correct or not. Possibly you had two versions of Google Maps API.

I would suggest removing and reinstalling Google Maps API and remaking the android project.